# Rails redirect_to different controller and then call method

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I'm working in Rails 4.1.8 and my app has an admin "dashboard" that uses its own basic AJAX navigation. I can navigate between the methods to "manage_customers", "manage_accounts", and "manage_acct_transactions" just fine. This app is a work in progress. Also working fine is performing some basic crud actions within these (AJAX rendered partial) views.

However,

After, for example, "Destroying" a customer I redirect to the main view of the admin. dashboard, which is **blank** because a "manage_foo" method hasn't been called.

This is my *destroy method* in my **Customers Controller** that is called by the dashboard view link:

```
  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to adminview_administrator_path, notice: 'Customer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

It gets me to the right place, but with NO CONTENT. **How can I perform this redirect and *then* call the manage_customers method** (below) to show the paginated customers list, "refreshed" of course without the deleted user.

**EDIT** Below is the *entire* administrators controller, added for better perspective.
My **Administrators Controller**:

```
class AdministratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  before_action :set_administrator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_admin

  # GET /administrators
  # GET /administrators.json
  def index
    @administrators = Administrator.all
  end

  def adminview

  end

  # Update adminview content using AJAX and jQuery
  def manage_accounts
    @accounts = Account.order('id').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js {render :manage_accounts}
    end
  end

  def manage_customers
    @customers = Customer.order('lastname').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :manage_customers}
    end
  end

  def manage_acct_transactions
    @acct_transactions = AcctTransaction.order('date').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js {render :manage_acct_transactions}
    end
  end

  # GET /administrators/1
  # GET /administrators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /administrators/new
  def new
    @administrator = Administrator.new
  end

  # GET /administrators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /administrators
  # POST /administrators.json
  def create
    @administrator = Administrator.new(administrator_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @administrator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @administrator, notice: 'Administrator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @administrator }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @administrator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /administrators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /administrators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @administrator.update(administrator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @administrator, notice: 'Administrator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @administrator }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @administrator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /administrators/1
  # DELETE /administrators/1.json
  def destroy
    @administrator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to administrators_url, notice: 'Administrator was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def require_admin
    unless current_user.role == 'admin'
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'NOT AUTHORIZED!! Redirecting to home page..'
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_administrator
      @administrator = Administrator.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def administrator_params
      params[:administrator]
    end
end
```

I've tried different syntax for the format.html in the destroy method, such as different paths, an action parameter, and changing the "format.html" to "format.js"

Here is the *routes.rb* (the part for the administrators controller stuff):

```
  resources :administrators do
    member do
      get :adminview
      get :manage_accounts
      get :manage_customers
      get :manage_acct_transactions
    end
  end
```

What needs to happen is redirecting to adminview.html.erb which has a div where I yield the output of the manage_customers function and related view. Which are as follows:

*manage_customers.js.erb..*

```
$('#displayArea').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'manage_customers') %>');
```

*_manage_customers.html.erb* (it's a partial) ..

```
  <h3>Listing All Customers</h3>
    <%= paginate (@customers) %>
    <table id="indexTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Customer ID</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Termination</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= '%09d' % customer.id %></td>
            <td><%= customer.lastname %>, <%= customer.firstname %></td>

            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <br>

  <%= link_to 'New Account', new_customer_path %>
```

All I want to do is call the manage_customers method of the administrators controller upon redirecting to the adminview from the destroy action of the customers controller. Just like what you'd see if you clicked "manage_customers" link in the adminview.

This should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you not create a method in your application controller, with a before action?

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :manage_customers

def manage_customers
    @customers = Customer.order('lastname').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :manage_customers}
    end
  end
```

This way you could call it on pages outside of the customers controller? This will call the before any other action in your application though, so you may have to set it to be more specific, or skip it on sub controllers.

eg. in application controller

```
before_filter :manage_customers, only: [:index, :show]
```

or in other controllers

```
skip_before_filter :manage_customers, except: [:index, :show]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get what that does, however, the before_action would need to have some way to conditionally run the method. The view I'm redirecting to is merely a shell which holds the content generated through the "manage" methods. I.e. you redirect to customers, accounts, or acct_transactions management, whichever one you were just on. Also, I'm sorry but I wasn't clear in stating that the "manage_customers" method isn't in the Customers controller but in a separate controller called Administrators (these actions  require authorization) Updated my post to show the whole controller.

Comment: In your applications controller, you could try wrapping the before action in a conditional if statement that checks the controller and/or the action being executed - for example `<% if controller_name == "administrators" && controller.action_name == "show"%>`

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer. However, I've scrapped the whole ajax navigation deal. No matter how I do it there are problems with CSRF errors due to Rails stateless nature. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped!